# Why array shall be used for sending one single object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concept, language-concepts

We were going through the Messenger [Broadcast API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/#creating) docs. It says:

> Only **one** message may be defined per Message Creative.

This **one** message is `<MESSAGE_OBJECT>` defined under an array named **`messages`**.

> *Not to offend Facebook developers*

My skepticism:

If only **one** message may be defined per Message Creative then why `messages` is an array?

Why array shall be used for sending one single object?

What could be the concept behind this?

Comment: I think that is because of [send api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api). It expects message to have property `text` as string. Though I agree it does not makes sense.

Comment: @Rajesh Still, why there is an array for a single object

Comment: Please ready my last sentence. I'll re-iterate *Though I agree it does not makes sense.* My suggestion is, try mailing to the support group. There are usually discussions that are internal, for design and architecture. They can share such doc/chat.

Comment: @Rajesh Sure, raised one for the same